# Compilation error after importing Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse

I am learning Java, and have created some simple code, yet ran into a compilation problem. I am using the eclipse IDE and this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

package myfirstjavaproject.example;

public class MyFirstClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at myfirstjavaproject.example.MyFirstClass.main(MyFirstClass.java:7)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must put `import` statements after the `package` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The `import` statement must appear after the `package` statement;

```
package myfirstjavaproject.example;

import java.util.Scanner; // <-- Here.
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your `import` statements have to be after your `package`. Like this:

```
package myfirstjavaproject.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFirstClass {
    //code here
}
```

You could think about it this way:

Java needs to know where you're importing stuff before you can use it, if you import it before you tell Eclipse what package you're using, it doesn't know where to import it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

After

```
package myfirstjavaproject.example;
```